# What does "say too much or too little" mean?

Tags: meaning

In "In the Midst of Alarms" (1894) by Robert Barr, Renmark wanted to tell someone that his son is missing, but he didn't want to alarm the boy's sister

> “Is your father in the house?”
>
> “Yes, but he is worried about mother. Tell me what it is. It is better to tell me.”
>
> Renmark hesitated.
>
> “Don’t keep me in suspense like this,” cried the girl in a low but intense voice. “Y**ou have said too much or too little**.

What does "say too much or too little" mean?

Comment: Why don't you translate that into your mother tongue? It would mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a surprise for you.

But I'm not going to tell you what it is.

You don't like not knowing, do you? I'm **keeping you in suspense**. I shouldn't have said anything (I've **said too much**), or else I should tell you what the surprise is (I've **said too little**).